# Why is the value of my input appearing blank?

Tags: jquery, input

I am writing a script that finds the value of a text input as it's typed.  For whatever reason, in console, the value is blank.

```
$('[rel^="liveSearch"]').ready(function(){

        var fieldName = $(this).attr("name");

        $(this).on('keydown', function(){                   

            console.log('A key was pressed... the value is '+$(this).val());

            if($(this).length > 3){

                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("rel") + $(this).val(),
                    dataType: "xml",
                    statusCode: {
                        404: function(){alert("404 not found!")}
                    }
                })
                .done(function(xml){
                    $(xml).find('member').each(function(){
                        var memberId = $(this).attr("id");
                        var memberName = $(this).find('content').text();
                        suggestionMenu.append('<li onclick="appendValue(\''+fieldName+'\', \''+memberId+'\');hideMenu(\''+suggestionMenu+'\');">'+memberName+'</li>');
                        suggestionMenu.show();
                    });
                });                 

            }

        });
    });
```

The message is logged in console, so I know that the on keydown function is called.  All console shows is "A key was pressed... the value is "... any ideas?

Comment: Post your markup or a fiddle.

Comment: You can sometimes get this if you accidentally import/embed the same JS file twice, worth checking in your resources tab of the inspector. Or add `debugger;` to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you using `$('[rel^="liveSearch"]').ready(`.

If that `input` is dynamically generated, use like this,

```
$(document).on('keydown', '[rel^="liveSearch"]', function () {
    var fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
    console.log('A key was pressed... the value is ' + $(this).val());
    if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("rel") + $(this).val(),
            dataType: "xml",
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert("404 not found!")
                }
            }
        })
            .done(function (xml) {
                $(xml).find('member').each(function () {
                    var memberId = $(this).attr("id");
                    var memberName = $(this).find('content').text();
                    suggestionMenu.append('<li onclick="appendValue(\'' + fieldName + '\', \'' + memberId + '\');hideMenu(\'' + suggestionMenu + '\');">' + memberName + '</li>');
                    suggestionMenu.show();
                });
            });

    }

});
```

It will work fine.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/135/)

Answer (score 0):

or use `String.fromCharCode()` to get the name of hit button

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/136/)